# A topological space $X$ who can be $drawn$, whose fundamental group is $S_3$

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, fundamental-groups

There exists an example of a topological space $X$ who can be $drawn$, whose fundamental group is $S_3$? I know that every group is the fundamental group of a topological space, but I need a concrete example.

Comment: I think the idea is to form a space whose fundamental group is $\langle a,b,c|a^2=b^2=c^3=abc=e\rangle$ (von Dyck groups).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An interesting question. In general you get $\langle a,b,c|a^m=b^n=c^l=abc\rangle$ as fundamental group of the $3$-manifold $\mathcal{L}/(m,n,l)$ where $\mathcal{L}$ is the connected Lie-group of orientation preserving isometries of the plane $P$ and $(m,n,k)=\langle a,b,c|a^m=b^n=c^l=abc\rangle$ is the orientation preserving transformations of a triangle with angles $\frac{\pi}{m}, \frac{\pi}{n}, \frac{\pi}{l}$ in the Euklidean, spherical or hyperbolic plane $P$, depending opon $\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{l}$ $ =1$, $>1$ or $<1$, respectively. (see [Gems, Computers and Attractors for 3-Manifolds
by Sóstenes Lins](https://books.google.de/books?id=TtTsCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA196&lpg=PA196&dq=fundamental%20group%20a%5E2%20b%5E2%20c%5E3%20abc%20presentation&source=bl&ots=X_uls3vkS9&sig=aNNmaR_e4-EWFoRDXpZYbBVNRoQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_wLjk97rRAhWCK5oKHeKTDQUQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=fundamental%20group%20a%5E2%20b%5E2%20c%5E3%20abc%20presentation&f=false)).

You should also read [ON THE 3-DIMENSIONAL BRIESKORN MANIFOLDS M(p,q,r)by John Milnor.](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/milnbries.pdf)

But there is an easier way.

Maybe you should think about $\langle a,b,c|a^2=b^2=c^3=abc=e\rangle$ or $\langle s_1, s_2 \mid s_1^2 = s_2^2 = (s_1s_2)^3 = e\rangle$ (see [groupprops.subwiki.org](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group:S3)) in terms of van Kampen to construct a space with this fundamental group.

First take $S^1\vee S^1$ (one cycle for each $s_i$) and three copies of $D^2$ to form the relation. The boundary of the first $D^2$ is glued to the cycle of $s_1$ by going twice around. Also the boundary of the second $D^2$ is glued to the cycle of $s_2$ going twice around. Then the boundary of the third $D^2$ goes three times around the whole $S^1\vee S^1$.

This should give your fundamental group. It will be hard to visualize, but I think it is possible by drawing things in a transparent way.